# Motorbike has no power, but kick start works

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, battery, lights

First up the motorcycle in question is a Skyteam V-Retro 250 (V-Raptor in some countries). On the way home last night I noticed that my tail lights weren't working so I bought a new bulb like I had done before and when I opened the tail light housing a few screws fell out and a wire (presumably earth)  and after I changed the light bulb non of the electrics are powering up when I turn the key.

I wasn't sure what to connect the earth wire to and tried a number of places and just from looking at the old light bulb I am thinking that it was not the reason for the rear light not working as it looks fine.

Now when I kick start the bike all the lights apart from the tail work but as soon as I kill the engine none of the electrics work, I can't turn on lights or use the electrical starter etc.

I have had a look at the battery terminals and cleaned them and they look in order but as much as I don't mind tinkering with the bike I don't know anything about wiring or the electrical bits so not even sure where to start.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!!

---

EDIT electrical diagram attached
[image: ST250 electrical diagram]

Comment: Can you find a wiring diagram and post it?

Comment: Yepp just posted it.

Comment: From the sound of it (because I faced a very similar issue with my bike), I think you  have your tail light wiring wrong. The easiest way to check this is to disconnect all the wiring in the tail light, start the bike, let it idle for 5 minutes or so and then check if the rest of your electricals are working right. If they are, try a different wiring combination for the tail light.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go this evening! By disconnect all the wiring I am assuming you mean taking the bulb etc. out and just have the three wires dangling at the back of the bike..??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From looking at your wiring diagram, you have clearly blown your main 15A fuse.  This explains why nothing is working from the battery, but once the engine is running, your magneto is powering all the electrics.

The disconnected wire must have shorted out and blown the fuse.

In the tail light, the green wire is the 'earth' wire.  The brown wire is the supply to the tail light bulb.  The Green/Yellow is the brake light supply.

Comment: Brilliant thanks!! Will try to get my hands on a new fuse and see if that sorts it!